# font changing doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, fonts, interface-builder

i want to change the font of a label from helvetica to calibri bold. so i chose calibri bold in the interface builder, but on my iphone it's sill helvetica. when i try to change it in the code like:

```
[label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Calibri Bold" size: 48.0]];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

the font on my iphone is helvetica 12.

where is the mistake?

thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is that the Calibri Bold font is not part of iOS.

You can supply it as a custom font, as a resource. Don't forget to add the relevant keys to the `info.plist`. It should be `UIAppFonts`, type array, containing the file names of the fonts. Then get the font name using `[UIFont familyNames]` - it may not match the file name.

Comment: Fair warning: legally speaking, he doesn't have the right to redistribute Calibri (it's a Microsoft font) so he is not allowed to do this.

Comment: i don't get it, what do i have to do? is there a tut for it?

Comment: You add the .ttf file as any other resource to your project. Then you look up the info.plist file, open it, and right-click "add row". The row should be named UIAppFonts (left side), its type should be array (right-click and change) and then you can add the names of the font files.

Comment: Oh, and then, in your app, put something like: `NSLog(@"fonts: %@",[UIFont familyNames]);` to see what name you should urse in the `setFont:` line in your code.

Comment: @Jonathan: he might be developing an app for Microsoft... but I guess you're absolutely right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Three things:
1) not every font in interface builder is available on the iphone
2) You have to choose the name which matches exactly the internal name for the font -- this is often not the IB "regular" name of the font.
3) make sure your outlets are correctly connected otherwise your code will not change the label.

Here's a link to the internal font names on the iphone: (kind of out of date but you can run his same code in your project to get the up to date list of names):

http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the font is available on iPhone?

[Here](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/) is a list of available fonts (maybe out of date, but...)